# xcode to crash due to reading when updating UI textField

Tags: xcode, crash

i am trying to update the collection view when text is entered in text field in UI.  i have sort of created an extension but when i call this function and call if after update to the UiTextField, Xcode crash with an error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not calling calling insertItems(at:)on your collection view.  Seems to be  collection view issue when running in Xcode - Recommend the following:

- To use delegation to pass events back to the view controller VC rather than having the header view and cells holding a reference to the VC.
- Avoid using term currentTagsArray may be.

Comment: Thanks.  Let me see if i can do that to reload and not affect the header at the same time.

Comment: Great.  also corrected the case issue with var name.  this helps! thanks!1